# Program crashes when reading first data point

Tags: c, struct

I want to see what student have the best mark in the class.
So I make this ,but i don't know where I am wrong

```
struct Date {
    char name[31];
    float mark;
};

struct Date * Read(unsigned int n,struct Date *d){

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        getchar();
        fgets(d[i].name, 31, stdin);
        scanf("%f",d[i].mark);

    }
    return  d;


}

int main(){

    unsigned int n;
    struct Date  *d;

    scanf("%u",&n);
    d = (struct Date*) malloc(n*sizeof(struct Date));
    d=Read(n,d);


    free(date);

    return 0;
}
```

after i read the mark the program crash.
Can someone help me and explain what to change?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `scanf("%f",d[i].mark);` --> `scanf("%f", &d[i].mark);`,  `free(date);` --> `free(d);`

Comment: Learn to format your code well. Everyone you work with will thank you for it. Example: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Usual hints: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 5):

The crash is most likely due to this:

```
    scanf("%f",d[i].mark);
```

You should pass the *address* as argument to read a float value. It should be:

```
    scanf("%f", &d[i].mark);
```

Technically, this is [*undefined behaviour.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Compile with all warnings enabled. gcc warns even without any specific options:

> warning: format %f expects argument of type âfloat *â, but argument 2 has type double [-Wformat=]
>            scanf("%f",d[i].mark);